# woocommerce - searchpage add to cart button redirect to homepage

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I created a custom search bar and when I search for a product, it displays a list of products with add to cart on the search page. when you press the add to cart, it adds to cart, but directs you to the homepage. I want it to stay on the search page.

Answer (score 0):

Install missing WooCommerce pages, go to **WooCommerce > Status > Tools** and use the page installer tool.

It should look like below:
[image]

Comment: that didn't change the outcome.